# openlayers display Control.MousePosition on div.olMap

Tags: openlayers-2, css

I have a map displayed in a div.
I have a small div named coordexterne displaying mouse position.
I try to put the small div on the map so to speak above the map. Until now, the small div is always under the map so it is unvisible, whatever i do in the css.

Any help ?

html :

```
<body>
  <div id="map" class="olMap">
    <div id="coordexterne"  ></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

css :

```
div.olMap {
border: 2px solid black;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
position: relative;
 }

#coordexterne {
font-family: Verdana ;
font-size: 10px;
text-align: right ;
width: 250px;
height: 15px ;
line-height: 10px;
position: absolute ;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
background-color: #6190FB ;
float: right;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you not just override the css from olControlMousePosition and the associated control?

Comment: that's what i am trying to do. I succeeded in positioning the block outside the map but inside it is hidden.

Comment: That is the default behavior -- that it sits above and inside map div. Perhaps you could post a jsfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a z-index property as described on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

for example

```
#coordexterne {
  ...
  z-index: 999;
  ...
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nzcktv9e/ , play with the z value and click run again to see the effect

Comment: I tried z-index: 0 for map and z_index: 1 for coordexterne. It failed. Besides, z-index is for img only (right?).

Comment: No, Z-index is for all elements

Comment: Maybe it's because of the positioning you specify? try setting bottom and right with your position (absolute/relative). See the CSS code in the fiddle I linked to.

Comment: Fine, I already had that result before. The problem is : I used your code and I always have a white stripe with height : 45px under div coordexterne, so my map is cut !! But you don't in your jsfiddle example...weird.

Comment: Weird...maybe you'll get more answers on stackoverflow.com; I am no JS/CSS guru and some of those guys are.

Comment: too bad, I was close to you result. Thanks anyway.

Comment: by the way, if it can help :

Comment: if it can be helpfull, I uploaded a picture to be clearer.